# VS2013 re-enable "Don't show this dialog again"

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was trying to update my service reference and I think there was a dialog that appeared warning about write/overwriting a read-only file.  I check the "Don't show this  dialog again" and now I want it to reappear.  Where is the setting for this?

BTW: Everytime I right click and choose Update Service Reference, it does its think and a DING sound occurs but no updates took place.  I would like to see the dialog again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Tools > Import/Export Settings > Reset All Settings`